# How do I calculate Nakshatram manually?

Tags: astrology, nakshatra

I want to calculate nakshatram manually.
Could you please explain me in detail?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. You just have to remember the following:

- Each zodiac sign has a total of 9 padas.
- There are 12 zodiac signs. So, 12*9 = 108 padas.
- Each nakshatra has 4 padas.
- Span of each pada is 3° 20′. So, 3° 20′*4 = 13° 20′(which is the span of one nakshatra)

So, start counting from Aries beginning with the nakshatra Ashwini, then Bharani and Kritika. These three nakshtaras fall in the zodiac sign Aries. 4 padas of Ashwini and Bharani and 1 pada of Kritika is in Aries (since a zodiac sign can have just 9 padas). The other 3 padas of Kritika falls in the zodiac sign Taurus.You will have to do this calculation for each sign or you can just use a vedic software which does the calculations for you.

You can also go through the detailed analysis here : *[“How To Calculate Tithi and Nakshatra & its Pada Manually?”](https://horoanalysis.wordpress.com/2017/02/20/how-to-calculate-tithi-and-nakshatra-its-pada-manually-an-article-written-by-vishal-aksh/)*

References: [here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-calculate-Nakshatra-Pada)