# How can we calculate the nakshatra starting time?

Tags: astrology, panchang, nakshatra

I have calculated the Nakshatra number and end time of Nakshatra.
I want to find the Nakshatra starting time for calculating the duration of the nakshatra.
Please help me to find nakshatra duration or nakshatra starting time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I calculate Nakshatram manually?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21329/how-do-i-calculate-nakshatram-manually)